# Plotting multiple plots on same page using gnuplot; trying to avoid text on the plot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, postscript

I am trying to plot multiple plots on the same page of gnuplot postscript output. Although, I like the way the plots are looking, what can I do to avoid the text on the plots? (See the code below, and the plot too). If you cannnot see the text on the plot, it says: "'../binsam_Omidi.dat' using 5:($1==1?$6:1/0)"

```
reset
set term postscript eps color size 10,10
set output "../Results/phasespace_bins.ps"


set multiplot layout 4,5        # engage multiplot mode
set size square
set size ratio -1

plot '../binsam_Omidi.dat' using 5:($1==1?$6:1/0) w p ps 1 pt 7 

set size 0.4,0.4       # set the size of the second plot in plot units
set origin 0.15,0.5    # set the origin for the second plot

plot '../binsam_Omidi.dat' using 5:($1==1?$6:1/0) w p ps 1 pt 7 
unset multiplot
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the legend (key) entry of the plot. You can specify your own title with the `title` option, like

```
plot x title 'my title'
```

If you don't specify your own title, the code of the plot command is used. This is what you see.

To have no key entry for a single plot use `notitle` or `title ''`. If you don't want to have any key at all use `unset key`.